# Replace the last six spaces with comma

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How would I replace the last six spaces with comma in a text file from each line with bash?

I have:

```
$cat myfile 
foo bar foo 6 1 3 23 1 20
foo bar 6 1 2 18 1 15
foo 5 5 0 15 1 21
```

What I want is:

```
$cat myfile
foo bar foo,6,1,3,23,1,20
foo bar,6,1,2,18,1,15
foo,5,5,0,15,1,21
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the rule could be to substitute any space before a digit for a comma:

```
sed 's/ \([0-9]\)/,\1/g' file
```

Alternatively, following your specification (replace the last six spaces), you could go for something like this:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF-6?FS:(i<NF?",":RS))}' file
```

This loops through the field in the input, printing each one followed by either a space (`FS`), a comma or a newline (`RS`), depending on how close it is to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

More complete sed with added rev (for reverse) might be

```
rev myfile | sed 's/ /,/; s/ /,/; s/ /,/; s/ /,/; s/ /,/; s/ /,/' | rev
```

sed part for first occurences of course can be simplified if needed!

Comment: This solution does not scale well. Alternatively you can replace all spaces after the sixth with newlines, then replace left spaces with commas, and reverse first substitution, like: `rev myfile | sed 's/ /\n/7g; s/ /,/g; s/\n/ /g' | rev`

Comment: more elegant i admit is 7g idea

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(.*) /\1,/;x;s/^/x/;/^x{6}/{z;x;b};x;ba' file
```

This uses greed to find the last space on a line and then keeps track of the number of spaces replaced by keeping a counter in the hold space.

Comment: interesting solution, btw what is this part {z;x;b} (btw upvote is from me). More preciously what are z and b there?

Comment: @josifoski 'z' see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands]), is used to remove all characters from the hold space i.e. reset the counter. `b` is the `goto` command in  sed, without a place holder it acts as a break command i.e. no further sed commands are processed.

Comment: tnx for explanation, only little correction, z is reseting pattern space as you used correctly (not hold) (from link which you've posted)

Comment: @josifoski sorry I misled you with my wording. The `z` command only effects the pattern space but what I meant was the values held in the hold space (which by the use of `x` become the pattern space) need to be wiped once the require number of spaces have been replace ready for the next line. HTH